# python: how to sort lists alphabetically with respect to capitalized letters

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list alphabetically, where capital letters should come before lower case letters.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'B', 'A']
```

`sorted(l)` should result in `['A','a','B','b']`

I've tried these two forms, but to no avail;

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda s: s.lower())
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B']
>>> sorted(l, key=str.lower)
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B']
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a tuple as your key instead:

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda L: (L.lower(), L))
['A', 'a', 'B', 'b']
```

This means the sort order for lower-case doesn't change `('a', 'a')` but means the first key for upper case puts it level with the lower-case equivalent, then sorts before it: eg `('a', 'A')` < `('a', 'a')`

Comment: Perfect solution. Sorry about my braindead previous comment :)

Comment: If you have non-english strings, be very careful of methods that rely on using `.lower()` for case insensitive sort, they work only for the ASCII subset of characters.  The proper way involves a bit of fiddling around with locale settings.

Comment: For example, this solution does not work for `lst = ['á', 'b', 'B', 'Á']` on python 2 (probably it will on python3)

Comment: @Wim on Py2... `['a', 'B', 'b', '\xc3\x81']` on 3.3: `['B', 'b', 'Á', 'á']`

Comment: only using regular letter characters btw: [a-z] and [A-Z]

Answer (score 5):

Interesting how such a list supposed to sort following list

```
lst = ['abb', 'ABB', 'aBa', 'AbA']
```

Proposed solution produce following result

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda L: (L.lower(), L))
['AbA', 'aBa', 'ABB', 'abb']
```

I can propose more complicated solution with different result

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda a: sum(([a[:i].lower(), 
                                    a[:i]] for i in range(1, len(a)+1)),[]))
['ABB', 'AbA', 'aBa', 'abb']
```

Comment: Good idea, but the expression could be simpler -- how about `[ord(x)+31.5*x.isupper() for x in a]`?