# Is there a python function that can sort a list based on capital letters?

Tags: python

I have a list such that:

`['DYLAN','BOB','ROB']`

Everything is capitalized, so I have written some python code that takes the first letter and then sorts it alphabetically, but  I am wondering now if I can do it with a python function. Thank you.

Comment: "*I have written some python code*" -- can you post this code please, so we can help you improve it?

Comment: Python's default `sort()` implementation on a `list` already sorts alphabetically.

Comment: From what little you've posted here, (1) you can simply use the existing sort functions; (2) you need to complete your research before posting a "question".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: After re-reading your question & the posted answers, this Q&A is basically "how to sort a list of strings in Python". If you [put that into the Stack Overflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+sort+a+list+of+strings+%5Bpython%5D), its already been answered previously (no surprise since its a standard task), so your question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case of the list does not matter when sorting. What you want could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581695/python-how-to-sort-lists-alphabetically-with-respect-to-capitalized-letters). In regards to converting to lower case, you can use list comprehension to convert all values of the list to lower case: `[c.lower() for c in yourlist]`. To learn more about list comprehension, I suggest you look [here](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/). Cheers

Answer (score 3):

list has a sort() function:

```
 l = ['DYLAN','BOB','ROB']
 l.sort()
 print(l)
 ['BOB', 'DYLAN', 'ROB']
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides `.sort()` which was already mentioned in another answer, you can also use `sorted()` like such:

```
sorted(["DYLAN", "BOB", "ROB"])
```